# Java textfield don't show unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode

I need to scan a QRCode (GS1 standard) with a hand in scanner and parse it into 4 elements.
2 of these 4 elements are of variable in lenght so they are followed by "GS" `GLOBAL_SEPARATOR \u001D`.

Example of **QRCode read** :

`01076127912745342191509713306750**GS**10SHU42**GS**17201231`

On this image you can see "GS" GLOBAL_SEPARATOR UNICODE from NotePad++

[image]

But when I read the QRCode from a hand in scanner in javafx textfield the unicode characters GLOBAL_SEPARATOR are not show when I make

```
myTextField.getText() => 0107612791274534219150971330675010SHU417201231.
```

How I can read unicode characters in my textfield to correctly parse it ?

Thank you

UPDATE:
With getBytes the GS group separator are not in

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Scan= ");
        BufferedReader buffer;
        int charRead;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String linein;

        try {
            buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));

            linein = buffer.readLine();

            byte[] b = linein.getBytes("UTF-8");

            // Displaying converted string after conversion 
            System.out.println("The String after conversion is : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(b[i]);
            }


        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }`
```

the GS should be between 4849, but nothing
`48494855544950555749505552535152504957495348575549515148545553**4849**4883728552504955504849505149`

WORKAROUND :

Configure on your hand in barcode scanner character conversion to convert GS to any other character that you can choose like ";" when you scan qrcode

the only disadvantage of this : need to configure your hand in scanner before use your software

Comment: GS is Group Separator, not Global Separator. It doesn't have any graphical appearance defined. It's just an ASCII control character. Notepad++ shows you a special graphic for it just for your convenience, and this is just a Notepad++ feature.

Comment: You might want to print the actual bytes value in order to make sure that your String actually includes the group separator using getBytes methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: @AntoineMottier with getBytes, GS unicode characters don't appears.

Comment: It sounds like the QR code reader is emulating a keyboard, but keyboard input doesn’t allow ASCII control characters such as GS (that would be equivalent to typing Ctrl-] on the keyboard).

Comment: On further testing, it looks like you **can** read GS from the keyboard, but you have to do it from a Command Prompt window, not from the IDE. Also, try inputting it into a JavaFX text field and then looking at it with getBytes(). Although instead of getBytes() it's better to use charAt() and display it using hex.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I found a workaround : i configure a character conversion on hand scanner to convert GS to ";", so when i read qrcode in java, i have this now : `01076127912745342191509713306750;10SHU42;17201231`

Comment: Create your own answer, as that work-around seems to be the only solution.

Comment: @JoopEggen it's not the *only* solution; just *a* solution. You can simply keep the GS but look for it in code instead of trying to print it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException it seems one cannot put it in a text field, so no further search worth there was what I wanted to say. Yes right.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own implementation of TextField.
Just copy TextField class and change a bit "insert" method.
Delete TextInputControl.filterInput(text, true, true) - here you loose your GS separator.